# Error while calling python via std::system

Tags: python, c++, qt, cmd, std

When I try to call python in c++ using this:

```cpp
QString command = "cd C:\\python\\python37 && python C:\\projects\\file_editor.py" 
QByteArray ba = command.toLocal8Bit();
const char *c_str2 = ba.data();
std::system(c_str2)
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

**edit:**
My python related path in PATH variable is:

```
C:\python\python37\Scripts
```

and i can use Qt
and i tried this as well:

```cpp
QProcess process;
QStringList pythonCommandArguments = QStringList() << "C:\\projects\\file_editor.py"
process.start("python", pythonCommandArguments);
```

but then i get this error:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process ("python") is still running.
```

Comment: `std::system(const('cd C:\python\python37 && python.exe C:\projects\file_editor.py'))` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: it was about the command so here you have the whole code

Comment: @Lua, are you sure?  `\f` is a valid escape character and I wonder why you take the pain to replace `/` by `\\`.

Comment: i work on windows so it needs to be \

Comment: This looks like a Python error, and has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: it is a python error

Comment: If you just do in the command prompt `cd C:\python\python37 && python C:\projects\file_editor`  Do you get the error?  If not that means the way you are forming the string for the system function is the issue.

Comment: if i do it in cmd i dont get the error

Comment: Your CMD environment may contain extra variables that are not present when you run it from your IDE.

Comment: If you do `std::system("cd C:\\python\\python37 && python C:\\projects\\file_editor" )` do you get the error?

Comment: Do you use any virtual environments?

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica i convert the qstring to a const char that is what argument system takes

Comment: @Lua I know, but to debug the issue this is part of the process.  Change your code to just be `std::system("cd C:\\python\\python37 && python C:\\projects\\file_editor");` and see if you get the error.  If you don't, then you know you are formatting the string incorrectly.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica nop still geting the same error

Comment: i also tried \\ but still same error

Comment: Okay, then your issue is with something in your environment.  If you use `std::system("cd C:\\python\\python37 && python.exe C:\\projects\\file_editor");`, do you still get the error?

Comment: yes i do get the same error

Comment: `'printenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file` ?

Comment: what now is this wrong?

Comment: @Lua my bad, I blanked on the fact that you are using Windows. It doesn't exist there. I don't know how to approach this on Windows.

Comment: Try `set` (with no parameters) in cmd and look for PYTHONHOME in the output. Then run `set` through `std::system` and compare the values.

Comment: i dont have pythonhome

Comment: do you really need to execute it in shell?

Comment: does the python command actually work if you don't invoke it from C++? than it's a C++ problem, if it doesn't work it's a python issue and this question should not have a C++ tag

Comment: it works from command line

Comment: just in case but from what drive are you running your program?
becuse if you have 2 drives the error will be clear

Comment: i use 2 drives indeed

Comment: and my program is on the other drive then python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **goal:**

execute a python script in c++

## **problem:**

using system or QProcess will give a error

## **solution:**

I think the problem is is that when you call python from a other drive it cant find the module so try placing your program on the same drive as python and it will work.

## **example:**

this is a quick example what your file tree can possibly mean

```
- pc
    - D
        [...]
        - myqtproject
            - source code
            - bin
    - C
        [...]
        python37
```

then this is wrong becuse python can't find any of his libaries now becuse it is on a other drive so you need to place your qt project on the C disk and it will look like this:

```
- pc
    - C
        - projects
            - myqtproject
                - source code
                - bin
        [...]
        python37
    - D
        [...]
```

and you need to replace 
`process.start("python", pythonCommandArguments);` with `process.startDetached("python", pythonCommandArguments);`
and this will work

Comment: Great that this works. I still don't see why it shouldn't work otherwise. Drive names can be part of PATH or PYTHONPATH. Perhaps there were read permission issues on C:\...\python37 ? THhs makes me curious.

Comment: Using diverent disks can always be confusing even I dont know why but i do know that it is there

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to cd into the directory of the python interpreter.

On the other hand many projects (if not nicely coded) might require you cd into the project's directory.

if nicely coded no cd at all is required

I would also use the py.exe wrapper, that is installed under windows it is intended to pick
the right executable and might take care of some env vars as well.
If you have multiple python versions installed I can show you how to select the right version with `py.exe`.

Try following two options:

```
QString command = "py.exe C:\\projects\\file_editor.py"
```

```
QString command = "cd C:\\projects && py.exe C:\\projects\\file_editor.py"
```

If you have encoding problems, then set the environment variable
`PYTHONIOENCODING` with `putenv()` to your desired encoding
'utf-8' / 'cp1252' or whatever you like.

I suggest you try first from the cmd line and only if you get it working from there you try it from C++

Example:

```
cd c:\projects
echo just some_text > stdin.txt
set PYTHONIOENCODING=cp1252
type stdin.txt | py.exe C:\projects\file_editor.py
```

I use the `type stdin.txt | py.exe ...` trick so, that I can simulate calling python without being attched to a console.

I don't have a windows PC with C++ installed, so I cannot test. but hopefully this (using py.exe and setting PYTHONIOENCODING explicitely) should put you on the right track

Comment: in console it works(what it al ready did) but in my c++ program it does not

Comment: does it work in the console with the **exact** commands that I suggested in my answer?

Comment: OK, and you tried C++ with putenv() **and** with py.exe?

And you still get exactly the same error?

Comment: Do you get an error if you try my example from cmd without the `set PYTHONIOENCODING=cp1252` line?

Comment: i dont get the error in cmd without the set pythonioencoding command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202922/discussion-between-gelonida-and-lua).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem similar to this then you have 2 options:

- add [user]\python[version]\ to path
- or like @matthijs990 said place the .exe on the disk with the python installation